# grep for multiple strings but print only the first match for each string in the list

Tags: text-processing, grep, gzip

```
zgrep -f /onip/appt/app/yemi/usage_biglist.txt \
    /onip/cdr/output/nor/bac/filec/$count/nordat.gz \
    >> /onip/appt/app/yemi/have_usage.txt
```

Summary

1. pick the first string in file `usage_biglist.txt`
2. grep it from file `nordat.gz` and save the result to `have_usage.txt`
3. pick next string in `usage_biglist.txt` and do the same till nth string

Answer (score 2):

`grep` (or `zgrep` in your case) will always output all matching lines from a file.

You could do each pattern match individually, and pass the result through `head -n 1` though:

```
while read -r pattern; do
    zgrep "$pattern" file.gz | head -n 1
done <pattern_list.txt >output_file.txt
```

In your case:

```
while read -r pattern; do
    zgrep "$pattern" /onip/cdr/output/nor/bac/filec/$count/nordat.gz | head -n 1
done </onip/appt/app/yemi/usage_biglist.txt >/onip/appt/app/yemi/have_usage.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `awk`:

```
gunzip < "/onip/cdr/output/nor/bac/filec/$count/nordat.gz" |
  awk '
    !list_processed {strings[$0]; next}
    {
      do_print = 0
      for (s in strings)
        if (index($0, s)) {
          delete strings[s]
          do_print = 1
        }
    }
    do_print
  ' /onip/appt/app/yemi/usage_biglist.txt list_processed=1 - \
    >> /onip/appt/app/yemi/have_usage.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
zgrep -m 1 -f
```

in the place of

```
zgrep -f
```

Comment: As far as I am aware this is a feature of GNU grep only. It is worth to mention it.

Comment: @Kalavan - even if OP was using gnu grep this doesn't do what they want i.e. print first match _for each string_ in the list

Comment: @don_crissti, You are right! I focused on a sub-problem and stopped there :/